# convert Doxygen HTML documentation to JSON/XML (aka reverse-generate documentation)

Tags: python, doxygen, maya-api

Maya has a pretty good [HTML documentation for their C++ API](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2020/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_annotated_html) (which I'm pretty sure comes from Doxygen).

However, the [Python docs/API](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2020/ENU/?guid=__py_ref_annotated_html) is lacking (eg no method return type information). If I had access to the docs in a structured way (JSON/XML/whatever), I could easily generate proper .pyi files with better type info.

Is there an easy way to convert Doxygen HTML documentation to JSON or something?

Comment: The Maya documentation definitely looks to be generated with doxygen but with an older version of doxygen (1.8.10) from June 2015. I'm not sure what you are exacly missing (example?) but besides HTML doxygen can also output XML

Comment: Well what I'm missing is the XML version :) ! I don't own that documentation so I have no way to re-generate it myself.

Comment: What info exactly are you missing here? Maybe it is present in a newer version of doxygen. Maybe you should contact for the information, maybe they can upgrade to a newer version of doxygen and / or make the XML documentation available.